# Unable to read repository at http://dpp.sourceforge.net/update/content.xml. Connection reset

Tags: java, eclipse

I get this error when I try to install Saros onto Eclipse for realtime collaboration. Any ideas why? I searched around and am still technically a beginner at coding and using Eclipse. I have already tried adding -vmargs -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true to my eclipse config file, but it did not work sadly.

Edit: It is a problem with SourceForge. Any link I go to belonging to that website leads me to a white blank webpage, with the website in a constant refresh. I have no idea how to fix it.

Comment: well I would say there is no such thing as "http://dpp.sourceforge.net/update/content.xml", or at least not from port 80. Have you tried the other installation method using Eclipse marketplace?

Comment: Yes, I have tried using dropins, or adding new software from inside Eclipse, and each time I get the same error. Is there any other real-time collab software, or am I stuck?

Comment: you tried the droppins "installation method" and you got the same error. There is a high chance that you are doing something wrong. Droppins installation method is fully offline (from Eclipse perspective) I would say, you should not even touch any update site if you just copy the plugins to droppins. Please do that again carfefully